# Proving (n+1-k)(n-k) / 2 from P(n+1-k)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, induction

A part of a proof by strong induction implementation is :

Given :

$P(K) = k(k-1)/2$

How to arrive at $(n+1-k)(n-k) / 2$ from $P(n+1-k)$ ?

Lecture screenshot (taken from MIT Mathematics for Computer Science) here : 
[image]

Update :

As $P(k)=k(k-1)/2$ should $P(n+1-k)$ not be $n+1- \frac{k\cdot (k-1)}{2}$ ?

Comment: Put K:=n+1-k. So easy.

Comment: For what $K$ are you given that $$P(K)=\frac{K(K-1)}2$$?

Comment: @Thomas Andrews I'm not sure I understand, P(K) holds for all values of K ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $l = n+1-k$, then $$P(l) = \frac{l\cdot (l-1)}{2} = \frac{(n+1-k)\cdot ((n+1-k)-1)}{2} = \frac{(n+1-k)\cdot (n-k)}{2}$$

EDIT:
$$(n+1-k) - 1 = n+1-k-1 = n-k+1-1 = n-k + (1-1) = n-k$$

Comment: how did you get from (n+1−k) to (n-k) ?

Comment: I didn't, I went from $(n+1-k) - 1 \to (n-k)$. I don't understand where your confusion lies

Comment: please see update, I think I'm not taking into consideration something fundamental

Comment: @blue-sky, are you familiar with the concept of a function?
Note that for a function $f$, in most cases $f(x+k) \neq x + f(k)$. I think you are focusing too closely on the $k$. Whatever is replaced by $k$ in $P(k)$ should also be replaced in $\frac{k(k-1)}{2}$

Comment: If the above comment continues to confuse you, you unfortunately may not be ready for MIT OpenCourseWare. Khan Academy has some good tutorials for beginner algebra.